# How to Call multiple methods on a single button click in android ?`

Tags: android, onclick, alarm

I implement so many methods but didn't get required results.
I want to call 2 methods on a single click button in Android.

I try the below code but it is not work for me.

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 switch (v.getId()) {

 case R.id.savebtn:   

   startAlert(); 

 default:
  break;
 }

}


 public void startAlert() {          

        EditText Start_alarm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.timeout_et);  
        int i = Integer.parseInt(Start_alarm.getText().toString());  

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);  
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(  
                                      this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);  
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);  
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()  
                                      + ((i * 1000)*60), pendingIntent);  
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set in " + i + " minute",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

        // App Exit here
        Intent intent_exit = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent_exit.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent_exit.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent_exit);
        finish();

        SetUpdateInterval();

    }

    //-------Repeating Video--------- 
 private void SetUpdateInterval() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);  
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);  

     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(  
             this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0); 
     EditText update_time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.updateinterval_et); 
     int j = Integer.parseInt(update_time.getText().toString());  
     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());          
     alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * j, pendingIntent);

}
```

Now, with this code only one method is call, i.e StartAlert(). I also want to call  SetUpdateInterval method.
So can anybody tell me, how cam i run these two methods simultaneously.

Thankx in advance.

Simplified code

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 switch (v.getId()) {   
 case R.id.savebtn:

   startAlert(); 
   SetUpdateInterval();

    finish();            
     break;

      case R.id.cancelbtn:
  finish();
        break;

 default:
  break;
 }
}

 public void startAlert() {  

        int i = Integer.parseInt(timeout_et.getText().toString());  
        System.out.println("VAlue of i" +" "+i);

        int j = Integer.parseInt(update_et.getText().toString());  

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);  
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(  
                                      this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);  
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);  
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()  
                                      + ((i * 1000)*60), pendingIntent); 
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()  
                + ((j * 1000)*60), j, pendingIntent); 
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set in " + i + " minute",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  

      }

   //-------Repeating Video--------- 
     private void SetUpdateInterval() {

         AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);  
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);  

         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(  
                 this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0); 
         EditText update_time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.updateinterval_et); 
         int j = Integer.parseInt(update_time.getText().toString());  
         Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
         calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());          
         alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * j, pendingIntent);

       // App Exit here
       Intent intent_exit = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
       intent_exit.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
       intent_exit.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
       startActivity(intent_exit);
       finish();

 }
```

Comment: ya so what is the prolem you getting in it? Any error are you getting?

Comment: Your `SetUpdateInterval()` never called because your `Activity` is finished before it.

Comment: Yes, i also want to finish my activity on that button too

Comment: @Khushboo But you can finish your activity after your `SetUpdateInterval()` method execute.

Comment: yes, i also do this but in that case my updateinterval is not run

Comment: See i want first to call StartAlert() and then my app would be finish, after then SetUpdateinterval() would be start

Comment: you are calling `MyBroadcastReceiver` so you can exit from app(means call that Activity) in `onRecieve` method of `BroadcastReceiver`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace below code, you are finishing activity before calling that method :

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 switch (v.getId()) {

 case R.id.savebtn:   

   startAlert(); 
   SetUpdateInterval()

 default:
  break;
 }

}
```

//Put below code in SetUpdateInterval() method for some delay and then do finish.

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        finish();

    }
},3000);
```

Comment: i am doing it in Activity

Comment: i think u fully cant get it my question...i'll tell u again

Comment: firstly i set timeout and update time. At first once alarm ring by Startalert method and then app would be exit then the alarm ring set by StartAlert() and after this again alarm ring which is set in Setupdate(). and this alarm repeats continously

Comment: @Khushboo Not getting your concern, I just want to tell you is, if everything working well then just concentrate to finish the Activity only.

Answer (score 0):

Call `SetUpdateInterval()` method before starting another activity and finishing current activity.